# Hide rows based on cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table of items and quantities, where I want to hide rows when the quantity is 0. The macro works, but it takes too long to complete.

This is the code:

```
Sub Hide2ndFix()
'
' Hide2ndFix Macro
'
BeginRow = 414
EndRow = 475
ChkCol = 24

    For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow
        If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value = 0 Then
            Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next RowCnt
'
End Sub
```

Is there a more efficient way of getting the same result, of hiding rows 414-475 if the value in column X is 0?

Comment: The problem is probably that there are calculations happening each loop.  The the beggining of the code add `application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` and at the end `application.Calculation =xlCalculationAutomatic`

Comment: Also this line `Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True` can be shortened to `Rows(RowCnt).Hidden = True`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The common way to make any code (that does any changing to the workbook) faster is by disabling `screen updating` and disabling `events` and changing the `calculation` mode to `Manual` (there are other ways, but these 3 things have the biggest factor).

And the the other thing is by collecting all rows in one union range has a big factor in deleting and inserting rows because the time that is needed to delete one row is similar to the time for deleting the whole union range. For example if deleting one row needs 1 second then deleting 1000 rows will need 1000 seconds, but deleting a union range that contains 1000 rows only needs 1 second.

Try this code:

```
Sub Hide2ndFix()
'
' Hide2ndFix Macro
'
Dim RowCnt As Long, uRng As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

BeginRow = 414
EndRow = 475
ChkCol = 24

    For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow
        If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value = 0 Then
         If uRng Is Nothing Then
          Set uRng = Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol)
         Else
          Set uRng = Union(uRng, Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol))
         End If

        End If
    Next RowCnt
'
 If Not uRng Is Nothing Then uRng.EntireRow.Hidden = True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: As always your code is succinct to the problem.  A little explanation as to what you are doing will make this a great answer, especially when deviating from the OPs base code.  Many who come here do not understand fully what is happening and a quick explanation can help them help themselves in the future.

Comment: @ScottCraner, my problem is I use google translation to write in english :). but i will try to explain what i change and hope not write anything wrong.

Comment: I understand, Do your best and, if you do not mind, others will help with the proper grammar corrections.  We just do not want to assume your intentions.

Comment: @ScottCraner, I will very happy if someone edit any of my posts to be in correct grammar .

Comment: @ScottCraner, thank you for the great edit, Now my answer is in correct english :).

Comment: my google translate attemp -- Rica ederim.  I hope I didn't just swear at you.

Comment: Thanks for the replies so far Fadi and Scott. I will endeavour to test this out when I get to the office in the morning and update you. Very much appreciated!

Comment: @Fadi okay I've got the above macro working like a charm! I don't suppose you'd be able to have a look at this other macro I'm using? It's a bit of a long one, again it works but very slowly. Is it best to post it as a comment here?

Comment: @iAGPx, I don't think you can post a long code as comment, and it is not good to post long code as new question in SO, but I think you can use `timer` in your code to see what part slow down it, then post only that part as new question including variables type and value like this question.

Comment: @Fadi I've posted another question.. hopefully you or someone will be able to help me out! Really appreciate the work you've done for me :) thanks